# How to listen events from amazon Neptune? Event Bridge possible?

Tags: amazon-neptune, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to listen events from event bridge for Neptune but not getting any luck.
I have tried event bridge rule to add amazon Neptune as a source but it is not working.
I am interested in events like, if Instance is created or DBcluster is created. I have also explored aws cloud trail to add as a source of event bridge but didn't work. Is event subscription in Amazon Neptune can help us this this way? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Subscribing to Neptune event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/events-subscribing.html)

Essentially the steps are to enable Amazon Neptune event subscriptions and chose which events you want to track (can be all events or a specific one), and where to deliver them. The notifications can be sent to e-mail, SMS, or to the ARN representing a Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic.

Using this approach you can have the event delivered to many different targets by SNS.

One of the targets that SNS supports delivering events to is AWS Lambda functions. As needed you could create a small Lambda function that puts the events into Amazon Cloud Watch Logs or many other destinations. SNS also integrates with Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose, which can be used to deliver events to targets such as Amazon OpenSearch Service, Amazon S3 and Amazon Redshift. You will find more details of how to use SNS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html) and application to application message delivery is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-system-to-system-messaging.html).

You can also use the CLI or SDK to create an event subscription. Using the CLI, this command will display the available options.

```
aws neptune create-event-subscription help
```

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin I was looking exact something like this. I managed to create event from Neptune event subscriptions and I also consumed events in Lambda by SNS target. One thing I am not sure which is mention in docs, "Amazon Neptune doesn't guarantee the order of events sent in an event stream. The event order is subject to change." . Would this have impact on events for instance create and other instance events? I am interested in event when instance is created and record it, curious if this is not in order and cause trouble..

Comment: It's only, at least for the most part, something to worry about in cases such as two instances restarting more or less at the same time. Whenever events are being delivered to systems such as e-mail and SMS you are also to some degree relying on the order in which that e-mail or SMS provider sends out the e-mail. The main spirit of the message is to not build order dependency into any code you have tracking events and to always check the timestamps.